# Switching Classes on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a question regarding simple Javascript function. Below is the code its easily visible that when a user clicks on the click button I want to switch classes I mean when the page loads "This is para" needs to be displayed then when the user clicks on click button the text needs to change to This is updated. but dont know why its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>untitled</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .none {
    display: none;
   }
 .display1 {
  display: block;
 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="default">This is para</p>
<p id="updated" style="display:none">This is updated</p>
<p><input type="button" value="Click" id="button1" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#default").addClass("none"); 
  $("#updated").addClass("display1");
 });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery's show() and hide() functions?

Comment: I can but just want to clear my concept about jquery.addclass.

Comment: @add class and remove class is mostly used to apply css property's at run time , for showing on and off you should use as others mentioned

Comment: @gov personally I disagree, mostly because it is more invasive. Manipulating element class keeps appearance decisions out of code in and the CSS where they belong. The code makes decisions and updates the logical *state* of the DOM.

Comment: Also @Jay may I suggest you come up with a better title for your question?  "javascript issue" is a little generic, don't you think?

Comment: @Pointy , if you want to change 10 property's for a div , is addclass not useful. Otherwise we have to keep adding one property by one for some many times.

Comment: yup agreed will take care of it.

Comment: @gov well it all depends on the situation. My experience is that it's easier to maintain the site as a whole when style/layout is as much under control of the CSS as possible. That way if he wants to change from "display: none" to some sort of greyed-out look, all that has to change is the CSS and the Javascript still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not just using `show()` and `hide()`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#default").hide(); 
  $("#updated").show();
 });

});
</script>
```

If you just want to change the text, instead of having two elements, why not remove the `updated` element and use `.text()`, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#default").text("This is updated");
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: If classes are needed for some reason, it's not working because he is not getting rid of the style="display:none;" on the second one (which your code will fix). So I'd recommend the OP use your code or if he needs classes, change `$("#updated").addClass("display1");` to `$("#updated").show().addClass("display1");` But of course, if that classes entire purpose is to show the paragraph, then it's pointless to use classes. Sorry for rambling. :)

Comment: @Andrew I don't think it's pointless to use classes that way - it's a perfectly sound approach. However, he shouldn't mix and match of course!

Comment: @Pointy Well, I think it's pointless if that's the only function and show() & hide() were made specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, but they *achieve* their purpose in a way that's not quite as clean. It embeds a layout/design decision in the Javascript code.

Answer (score 4):

Do this instead:

```
$("#default").hide(); 
$("#updated").show();
```

And you can get rid of the `none` and `display1` classes.

What's happening to you is that the `style="display:none"` takes precedence over a class, so it will never show that way.

Comment: but I dont want #updated to be displayed the first time when the page is loaded.

Comment: you can add `style="display:hidden;"` to the #updated element. `show()` will still work then

Answer (score 1):

Your "addClass" call is (probably) working, but the style directly on the element trumps the style offered by the CSS.

Personally I *prefer* to do that sort of thing by changing "class" values like that, but you can't really mix and match the two approaches. (Well, you *can*, but it's confusing and error-prone.)  Instead of starting your element with that style, give it instead your "none" class.